# How to deal with wrong appSettings in a static class?

Tags: c#, parsing, type-conversion, app-config, static-classes

I'm working with a static class, which should decide whether or not to log information.

It started with:

```
public static bool ShouldLog { get; set; } = true;
```

I decided to use an application setting for this:

```
public static bool ShouldLog { get; set; } = 
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"];
```

This does not work, because `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` returns a string, so this needs to be parsed:

```
public static bool ShouldLog { get; set; } =
  Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"]);
```

This is also not good, because, when nothing is filled in in the application.config file, this will generated a `NullReferenceException`, hence the next attempt:

```
public static bool ShouldLog { get; set; } =
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"] == null ? false :
    Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"]);
```

This is also not good, because when somebody has entered nonsense into the application.config file, this will generate a `TypeInitializationException` exception, so the next attempt:

```
public static bool ShouldLog { get; set; } = 
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"] == null ? false : 
    Boolean.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"]);
```

This does also not work, because the signature is not `result = TryParse()` but `TryParse(..., out result)`, so now I'm out of options:

I would like something like:

```
bool ShouldLog = ...(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"]);
```

Expected result :

- `true` or `false` if `application.config`'s entry is `TRUE` or `FALSE` (case insensitive is preferred).
- `false` if `application.config`'s entry is anything else.
- `false` if `application.config` does not contain the expected entry.

Comment: I suggest to throw an exception when the string contains unexpected value, otherwise you may spend a whole day figuring out why the logs are not output if someone types `тrue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to achieve the precise goal of what you're asking, you could use:

```cs
public static bool ShouldLog => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShouldLog"]
    ?.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true;
```

However, I'd personally recommend that instead you use an existing, commonly-used logging framework that provided configuration support, instead of rolling your own. That's likely to provide much more flexibility, as well as avoiding reinventing the wheel.